# After translate animation button click not working

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

when i click a button the translate animation starts. then button placed where translate animation gets end. it working good but after animation button click not working. 
thanks in advance

```
public class ButtonFragment extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{

private Button btn;
private int width;
private Boolean flag = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_button_fragment);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TranslateAnimation animation = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn:

        if(flag ==  true) {             
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, width-92 , 0, 0);
            flag=false;
        }
        else{
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(width-92,0 , 0, 0);
            flag = true;
        }

        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        btn.startAnimation(animation);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }



  }
           }
```

code proper alignment was done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As given in [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html):

> Another disadvantage of the view animation system is that it only modified where the View was drawn, and not the actual View itself. For instance, if you animated a button to move across the screen, the button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to handle this.

Try using property animation and read the link given above.